# What is the conditional expectation?

Tags: probability, expectation, conditional-expectation

> What is the conditional expectation of:
>   $$\mathbb{E}\left[(X_1+X_2)^{10}\mid X_1\right]$$
>   with $X_i$ i.i.d: $P(X_i=1)=0.5=P(X_i=-1)$, for $i=1,2$.

How do I need to start this? I guess, I need to rewrite $(X_1+X_2)^{10}$? And eventually take out what is known, which is the $X_1$. Can someone help on how to start with this?

Comment: The information you provided is not sufficient. One needs to know the *joint* distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$, not just the individual distributions. I suspect that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, but I am not sure in this.

Comment: Yes, sorry they are i.i.d

Comment: Given $X_1$ there is a $\frac 12$ probability that $(X_1+X_2)^{10}$ is $0$ and a  $\frac 12$ probability that $(X_1+X_2)^{10}$ is $2^{10}$ so...

Comment: Fun fact: $(X_1+X_2)^2$ is independent of $X_2$ because $X_1X_2$ is independent of $X_2$... and the result follows.